# apt-get install from local repository

Tags: server, apt, package-management, localrepository

I have two Ubuntu 14.04 servers. Server 2 is a repository server and server 1 does not have internet access.

Repository server Configuration:

nginx with root directory: `/var/www/packages`
All packages including Packages.gz are in `/var/www/packages/amd64` path

My Server config:
in `sources.list.d/local-repo.list` there is

```
deb http://my-repo-ip amd64/
```

`sudo apt-get update` is successful with no errors. But:

```
$ sudo apt-get install {package}
....
....
After this operation, **.* MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!

Err http://my-repo-ip/ amd64/ {package}
404  Not Found
Err http://my-repo-ip/ amd64/ {package-dependencies}
404  Not Found
....
E: Failed to fetch http://my-repo-ip/./{package-dependencies}.deb 404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://my-repo-ip/./{package-dependencies}.deb 404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://my-repo-ip/./{package}.deb 404  Not Found
```

The exact packages exists of course in my repo amd64/ directory. Does anyone know how to help with this cause i have run out of ideas?

Thanks.

edit: `wget http://my-repo-ip/amd64/Packages.gz` from my server works as charm.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt-get install {package} --print-uris`?

Comment: `'http://my-repo-ip/./{package-with-version}' {package-with-version} 3890560 MD5Sum:b21837e6f61417477c58bc05ed8cfd24`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the `sources.list.d/local-repo.list`

i had: `deb http://my-repo-ip amd64/`

and i changed it to: `deb http://my-repo-ip/amd64/ ./`

and worked like a charm!